# includepdf addtotoc bookmark encoding

Tags: hyperref, pdfpages, font-encodings, bookmarks

When I use `includepdf` [`addtotoc`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf#page=6) option with `pdflatex`, bookmarks generated by this command produce gibberish:

[image]

This is the code:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[bookmarks,pdfencoding=auto,psdextra]{hyperref}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\chapter{Глава 1}
\section{Секция 1}
Текст
\section{Секция 2}
Текст

\includepdf[pages=-, addtotoc={1, chapter, 1, Чертёж, app:drawing}]{drawing.pdf}

\end{document}
```

And `drawing.pdf` is actually just the first page of this document:

```
> pdftk test.pdf cat 1 output drawing.pdf
```

How can I fix bookmark encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what pdfpages is doing here. But you can externalize the toc entry:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[bookmarks,pdfencoding=auto,psdextra]{hyperref}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\chapter{Глава 1}
\section{Секция 1}
Текст
\section{Секция 2}
Текст

\clearpage
\refstepcounter{chapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\chapternumberline {\thechapter}Чертёж}
%
\includepdf[pages=-]{example-image}

\end{document}
```